# How to read VHS using rawvideo

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, video-capture, vhs

I want to digitize old VHS tapes on Windows 10.

```
ffplay -hide_banner -f dshow -rtbufsize 2048M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Ligne (Dazzle Video Capture USB Audio Device)"
```

It is not perfect but it works

I don't want change the format because my computer have a poor CPU 1.4Ghz but 16 GB RAM

My idea is to digitize in `rawvideo` format. I know it will give a big file.

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -async 1 -vsync 1 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2048M -i video="Roxio Video Capture USB":audio="Ligne (Dazzle Video Capture USB Audio Device)" -c:v copy -c:a copy "Good Movie3.yuv"
```

Output is black screen.

```
ffmpeg version 2021-01-09-git-2e2891383e-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 63.100 / 56. 63.100
  libavcodec     58.115.102 / 58.115.102
  libavformat    58. 65.101 / 58. 65.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 95.100 /  7. 95.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Roxio Video Capture USB:audio=Ligne (Dazzle Video Capture USB Audio Device)':
  Duration: N/A, start: 429807.930000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'Good Movie3.yuv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1299 fps= 22 q=-1.0 Lsize=  779400kB time=00:01:00.84 bitrate=104932.8kbits/s speed=1.01x
video:779400kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

So a parameter is missing or too much.

Comment: *"Output is black screen."* What player are you using? Note that `.yuv` will not keep the audio: consider `.mkv` or some other container.

Comment: Maybe it "captured" a black screen? I.e. that's not a wrong output and in the *.yuv file  really stored a black screen, but a wrong input selection / configuration? (That you have `-c:v copy` also suggests that.) Are you sure this capture card supports raw video?

Comment: I use virtualdub2. I read in command log Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc  And if i use ffplay it is ok!

Comment: with .mkv i see now but a lot of dropped frames. VHS is very good on TV (for VHS of course) perhaps rise rtbuffersize? i have 16G RAM.